# Snapshot of Physical Machine using Azure Backup

Tags: azure, backup-restoration

In Azure Backup Service, we can backup files and folder but can I backup full OS along with data of Physical Machine and restore it on the same/other Physical machines?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, apparently as long as you have a DPM Server or an Azure Backup Server.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-introduction-to-azure-backup

This says it supports Bare Metal Recovery, which is what you need to restore onto different hardware.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-backup-faq

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i want to know more precisely i.e suppose i have my windows 7 laptop and i can backup / snapshot of whole machine  using Azure Backup Server (can be in another Machine). Is it so?

Comment: Also i am lil bit confuse about diffence between things they can protect i.e. Volumes , Applications and Workloads respective to my physical machine. Does any of these three means i can backup whole laptop i..e OS with Data?

Comment: Yes. Please consider this logically - if it can do BMR (as it says in the second link), then that's the whole machine it's backing up. Have you tried researching and implementing this yourself?

Comment: I tried with backup agent but not with backup server yet.

Answer (score 0):

> can I backup full OS along with data of Physical Machine and restore
>   it on the same/other Physical machines?

Yes, we **can** use the Recovery Data wizard in the Microsoft Azure Recovery Services (MARS) agent to restore data.

> Restore data to the same machine from which the backups were taken.
>   Restore data to an alternate machine.

More information about **restore data from a backup vault**, please refer to this [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/backup/backup-azure-restore-windows-server).